# Is it good to call setContent from shouldKeepOnScreen?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-splashscreen

I'm trying to implement a splash screen via [SplashScreen compat library](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen). Also, I use Jetpack Compose to implement UI and Jetpack Compose Navigation to implement navigation.
I have two screens: a login screen, a content screen. When a user opens application I should show:

1. The content screen if the user is already logged in.
2. Otherwise, the login screen.

I have the following idea:

```kotlin
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        private var job: Job? = null
        private var keep = true
        
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                if (job != null && keep) {
                    return@setKeepOnScreenCondition true
                }
                if (!keep) {
                    return@setKeepOnScreenCondition false
                }
                job = lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val startDestination = if (isUserLoggedIn()) { //Let us imagine that it is a long operation, so it's a suspend method
                        "content"
                    } else {
                        "login"
                    }
                    setContent {
                        NavHost(..., startDestination = startDestination) {
                            composable(route = "login") { ... }
                            composable(route = "content") { ... }
                        }
                    }
                    keep = false
                }

                return@setKeepOnScreenCondition keep
            }

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        }
    }
```

**Question:** is it safe to call `setContent` from `setKeepOnScreenCondition` like this?